# How to hide a menu on outside click when menu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have read a lots of solution but failed to achieve this feature. How to columns menu on outside of the menu element click.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxegEG

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
     $('#toggle').toggleClass("on"); 
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
/* Important styles */
#toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
}

#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -9px;
}
#toggle span:after{
  top: 9px;
}
#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#toggle span,
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #888;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* on activation */
#toggle.on span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle.on span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
#toggle.on span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
#toggle.on + #menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* menu appearance*/
#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
ul, li, li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}
li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method checks all swipes and clicks on the document to make sure they are not directly interacting with the button or the menu using e.target.

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#toggle').toggleClass("on");
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('touchstart click', function(e) {
  const toggle = $('#toggle'),
    menu = $('#menu');

  if (
    toggle.hasClass('on') &&
    !menu.is(e.target) &&
    menu.has(e.target).length === 0 &&
    !toggle.is(e.target) &&
    toggle.has(e.target).length === 0
  ) {
    toggle.removeClass('on');
  }
});
```

```css
/* Important styles */

#toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
}

#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -9px;
}

#toggle span:after {
  top: 9px;
}

#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#toggle span,
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #888;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* on activation */

#toggle.on span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#toggle.on span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

#toggle.on span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}

#toggle.on+#menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* menu appearance*/

#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}

#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}

ul,
li,
li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}

li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```